# copy part of string to other field using reg expression, in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have 2 fields in my table: `start_date` and `title`.
`start_date` is NULL.
`title` contains string like this: 'treatment at date 11/12/2012, at ... `'.
I want to copy only the date into`start_date`(from`title` field.)

what query will do that?
Thank you very match!

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done using only MySQL, I think you'll need to use a language liek PhP to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Mysql's support for regexp is only used in the where-part.

You have to either extract it into something else (java, perl, ruby) and manipulate it there or you can try to use [locate, substring and other string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) (but none of them are regexp)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL support for regular expressions is very limited, but if the format of your title column is almost fixed, and the date is always followed by ', at  ...' you could use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in conjunction with two [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET start_date = STR_TO_DATE(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ', at', 1), ' ', -1), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

The first SUBSTRING_INDEX will return everything before the first ', at' substring, and the second one will return everything after the last space fount.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03ecc5/1).

I considered dates in the format of day/month/year, if it is month/day/year just use '%m/%d/%Y'